# List<T> inside serializable object not deserializing correctly in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have this object called MyObject in C# and I've been trying to make it so that we can take this object, serialize it to JSON, use that JSON to populate other lists in JavaScript, etc, and then use the resulting changed JSON string to be fed back into the MyObject object and change its values. However, whenever I call Json() on this object, it gives me correctly serialized JSON, but when I feed that exact JSON back into the UpdateFromJson(string json) method, it claims that the List is of count=0 and I get none of my List objects in the new object. The other properties populate just fine; the only problem is with the List.

Here is the (dumbed down) class without the properties but with the relevant methods and List of objects. It should be noted that the List contains objects that I defined elsewhere in the namespace, i.e. they're not in the C# framework anywhere, they're custom.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject
{
  public MyObject()
  {
    this.Elements = new List<MyObjectElement>();
  }

  public List<MyObjectElement> Elements { get; private set; }

  public string Json()
  {
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(this);
  }

  public void UpdateFromJson(string json)
  {
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    MyObject temp = serializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(json);

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in temp.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
      object value = property.GetValue(temp, null);
      if (value != null)
      {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof (List<MyObjectElement>))
        {
          foreach(MyObjectElement le in (List<MyObjectElement>)value)
          {
            this.Elements.Add(le);
          }
        }
      }
      property.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
  }
}
```

Like I said, the only issue I'm having is, for example when `serializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(json)` happens, the List has nothing in it when, in fact, the actual JSON string (I've had it printed to a browser and have tested it in JSONLint) contains data for Elements. It just seems that `Deserialize(json)` is not able to retrieve the List in a format it can parse, or something, I'm not sure.

Comment: Presumably the List gets ignored while deserializing because your Elements setter is private. I have not checked it but i doubt the serializer will use the Add Method of the Existing List while deserializing but will create a new one and isn't allowed to set it.

Comment: @Ralf Nice catch. So, when I remove that private and allow it to set, I had an error for not having a parameterless constructor in my MyObjectElement object. I added one and now I get `Cannot deserialize object graph into type of 'MyObjectElement'`. Now, there are other objects that extend MyObjectElement (which is abstract because of this) and **those** are what are in `Elements`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ralf ...and after I think for a minute I make `MyObjectElement` _not_ abstract just to see what happens and it is trying to instantiate these `MyObjectElement`s. So, I'd have to add another check inside the `foreach(MyObjectElement le in List...)` to ensure that it adds a non-truncated version of the MyObjectElement to the list. If your comment was an answer, I'd mark it correct.

Comment: Are you trying to deserialize any inherited MyObjectElement type? The Json doesn't contain any type information. So how should the Serializer deserialize the json to the correct type? Guessing from the found Properties? What if two type have the same surface? Sorry i believe you need a concrete creatable Type here. Or some kind of a Custom Type Resolver to ~help~ the Serializer to find the correct type.

Comment: What I plan on doing is having several `List`s inside of the `MyObject` class that each contain a `List<ExplicitType>` so that the information is saved because it can be Deserialized safely. I believe that will work.

Comment: OT:  Is there a difference between `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` and `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer`?  Is one better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ralf had suggested, I had the setter for my internal List as private. I changed that and it triggered a bunch of refactoring. What ended up happening is that I chose to have explicit Lists for each Type that extended MyObjectElement so that when serializing to JSON it can deserialize without loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the equality check for `typeof(List<MyObjectElement>)` is failing. Possibly the type that is being deserialized is array or IList or otherwise. Can you not just use the object that is deserialized in place of this object and map it outside of the object? Why map it within itself?

Comment: Well, I know that it enters that part of the code as I've debugged to ensure that. So it gets the `Type`, but the `List` itself has no elements in it. For example, this is what the actual JSON is: http://pastebin.com/VwzGJ61k

Comment: What does the temp object have in its list at that point in the code?